# Print only the first word of each paragraph using sed

Tags: sed

I am wondering how I can print out only the first word of every paragraph with a sed one-liner. A paragraph in this case is defined by a text that follows 2 line breaks.

e.g.

```
This is a paragraph with some text. Some random text that is not really important.

This is another paragraph with some text.
However this sentence is still in the same paragraph.
```

this should be transformed to

```
This

This
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible `GNU sed` solution would be:

```
sed -rn ':a;/^ *$/{n;ba};s/( |$).*//p;:b;n;/^ *$/ba;bb'
```

Output:

```
This
This
```

It treats spaces-only lines as empty and understands any number of empty lines between paragraphs. Also processes one-word paragraphs correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Think 
[paragraph mode](http://gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html)

```
By a special dispensation, an empty string as the value of RS indicates that 
records are separated by one or more blank lines.
```

`awk` or `perl` have support for a 'paragraph mode' and either would make a better choice than `sed`:

```sh
awk '{ print $1 }' RS= ORS="\n\n" file
```

or

```sh
perl -00 -lane 'print $F[0]' file
```

Results:

```
This

This
```

Comment: Just a side note, if you wanted the record separator to be _exactly_ two line breaks, use `RS="\n\n"` for `awk`. Can't remember how to do it in `perl` on the cmd line. Maybe someone else here would know?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/\n\s*$/!ba};s/\s.*/\n/' file
```