# how to pass tcsh variable to perl one-liner

Tags: perl, tcsh

can you please tell me how to pass the cshell variable to a perl one liner?  i expect the script to print out AAA but it ends up giving me an error: Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -fb

set myvar = "AAA"
perl -e "print $myvar"
```

the more complex case for my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -fb

set myvar = "AAA"
perl -ne 'if (/$myvar/) {s/m1/m2/g}' fileA
```

Comment: actually this is just a simplified version of my script, i would like to process an input file said fileA....my script is something like: perl -ne 'if (/$myvar/) {s/m1/m2/g} fileA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass on my Bash loop variable to the Perl interpreter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974493/how-can-i-pass-on-my-bash-loop-variable-to-the-perl-interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables from the host system are available in Perl's [`%ENV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvars#ENV) variable. But to mark a variable as inheritable you have to use csh's `setenv` builtin instead of `set`.

```
% setenv myvar AAA
% perl -e 'print $ENV{myvar}'
AAA
```

(Note the single quotes in the argument to `perl -e`)

Answer (score 1):

Your perl statement is `print 'AAA'`, so you need to pass the single quote in.

```
set myvar = "AAA"
perl -e "print '$myvar'"
```

In the other case, you need to use double-quotes to let Perl get the value of your variable.

```
set myvar = "AAA"
perl -ne "if (/$myvar/) {s/m1/m2/g}" fileA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `myvar` as command line argument to your `perl` program.

Comment: hi Bill. see my comment above

Comment: Can you please share some code to help me understand. Can you pass the filename as an argument to the perl script?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/tcsh -fb
    
    set myvar = "AAA"
    perl -ne 'if (/$myvar/) {s/m1/m2/g}'

Comment: Can you pass `myVar` as an argument and use `ARGV[0]` instead of `$myvar`?

Comment: can you show me how to pass both myvar and fileA to the perl 1liner?

Comment: BTW, if all you are doing is `search and replace`, you may consider using `sed -i` or something similar along these lines.

Comment: You can pass both of them as command line arguments. Pls look at this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321829/how-do-i-best-pass-arguments-to-a-perl-one-liner

Comment: does SED support paragraph mode?  like perl -00 ?

Comment: This may be useful -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385720/print-only-the-first-word-of-each-paragraph-using-sed